# (android.content.Context) in NotificationManagerCompat cannot be applied to

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to initialize the NotificationManagerCompat in a fragment, but aparently I can't do that as it needs to be initialized in an activity.  Here is code and error I get when I try to do it in a fragment

So what I am wondering is, if I initialize and move all the notification code to MainActivity, can I still call it from my fragment? Cause I want the alert to trigger whenever a timer in the fragment is finished. Or is there a different way to make it work inside my fragment? Just a little unsure about how to go about doing this. Thanks!

```java
private NotificationManagerCompat notManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);

        notManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

//this is error I get from passing in this

(android.content.Context)
in NotificationManagerCompat cannot be applied
to
(x.gmail.com.insulincalc.TimerFragment)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments themselves are not a `Context`, but they have a `getContext()` method that returns a `Context` object you can pass instead of `this`:

```
notManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
```

Note that more recent versions of Fragments also contain a `requireContext()`, which returns a guaranteed non-null `Context`. You should consider using that to avoid Lint warnings about using a nullable Context when a non-null Context is required.